# How to continuously loop 2 python scripts?

Tags: python

I have 2 separate python files that are meant to be played one after the other. They are fairly large and I didn't want to merge them into one to avoid using the same variable names and such. Is there a simple way where when one script finishes, I can run the second script in the first? And if so can I make this loop infinitely?

Comment: this seems easy with e.g. a shell script managing it. `while :; python script1.py; python script2.py; done`

Comment: For a large script, the Python best practice is for each script is to decompose it into one or more function calls then have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` section at the bottom that calls it. That also makes handling this interleaving easier, if you want to do it inside Python (and get logging, debugging, output redirection etc.).

Comment: @12944qwerty: no it can't, nowhere did I say 'a imports from b and b imports from a'. A third Python script imports both a and b and does the interleaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply import both files and run each function.

a.py

```
import b
import c
b.run_b()
c.run_c()
```

b.py

```
import time
def run_b():
    print('there')
    time.sleep(2)
```

c.py

```
import time
def run_c():
    print('hello')
    time.sleep(2)
```

you'll see when you run `a.py` you will see a pause between outputs.

Comment: I'd considered this, but when the OP says "two python scripts" I expect they are just imperative top-to-bottom scripts, not a set of function definitions that one might import and run.

Comment: If there is no function you can just do `import b`then `import c`

Answer (score 0):

Use a third python file to manage this. Import the 2 other ones as modules in the new one. Note that what user smci comments about using `if __name__ == '__main__':` is extremely valid. Read [this short article](https://medium.com/python-features/understanding-if-name-main-in-python-a37a3d4ab0c3) for a simple explanation.

There's some cave-ats I will mention immediately.

- The code that is at base level (the code that is not indented) gets executed as soon as the python file is imported. Put your code in a function code block `entryfuction()`
  to be able to run the same code multiple times without previous exectutions affecting new runs of the code. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) for explanation about python code execution. See [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) for a short explanation about variables. Since the modules will stay loaded, any global variables will *remember* the value they had at the end of the last execution (which *could* be the time the module got loaded).
- Infinite loop

  - Infinite loop

    - Infinite loop

      - Inifinite loop (You get the idea)

The basic way to infinitely loop is using the below for the 3 modules.

New module:

```py
import module_1_filename
import module_2_filename

def endlessloopfunction():
    while True:
        module_1_filename.entryfuction()
        module_2_filename.entryfuction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    endlessloopfunction()
```

File module_1_filename.py

```py
print("I'm running at root base block level in module 1")

def entryfuction():
    print("I'm running at function level in module 1")
```

File module_2_filename.py

```py
print("I'm running at root base block level in module 2")

def entryfuction():
    print("I'm running at function level in module 2")
```

Save & run these 3 and see the fun happen in your terminal. Change the new third module to the one below to actually see what happens with the print statements:

```py
import module_1_filename
import module_2_filename

def notendlessloopfunction():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        module_1_filename.entryfuction()
        module_2_filename.entryfuction()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    notendlessloopfunction()
```

Running this will show that the *root level* print statements from the 2 imported modules only get run once, and this happens at the time they get imported in the third module.